# how to use regex to strip the preprocessor directive

Tags: regex

FI have many code which contains code snippet like:

```
#if wxCHECK_VERSION(2, 9, 0)
Codef( _T("%AAppend(%t)"), ArrayChoices[i].wx_str());
#else
Codef( _T("%AAppend(%t)"), ArrayChoices[i].c_str());
#endif
```

But I want to clean the code to

```
Codef( _T("%AAppend(%t)"), ArrayChoices[i].wx_str());
```

I mean, I need to strip the preprocessor directive, and only leave the first branch.

The match condition should be:

```
#if wxCHECK_VERSION(2, 9, 0)
blablabla1
#else
blablabla2
#endif
```

The content of `blablabla1` and `blablabla2` should be the same only except the `wx_str` and `c_str`.

See here, someone said it can be handled by regex, but I have no idea, can you help me? Thanks.

EDIT:
I just want to strip the #else branch, and only keep the first branch contents.

Here is the reference page:

[Re: what's the best and quick way to remove all the wx_str and c_str preprocessor](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,16680.msg113264/topicseen.html#msg113264)

Comment: I don't quite understand. As you describe the desired output it's identical to the input.

Comment: Do you care about nested `#if` constructs? What language do you want to implement in? Do you have a manageable filesize (<100MB)? Depending on that a dumb three-state machine or a parser creating some sort of tree might be best. The Regexes get comlicated as soon as you have nested conditions…

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just want to strip the #else branch, and only keep the first branch contents.

Comment: @amon, I do not care about nested #if, I only care about the code pattern I post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Search

[This regex](http://regexr.com?31omq) works for your examples:

> `\s+#if wxCHECK_VERSION\(2\, 9\, 0\)\s*(.*?)wx_str([^\r\n]*?)\s*#else\s*(\1)c_str(\2)\s*#endif`

## Replacement

**Regexr.com**: Replace with: `$1wx_str$2`. Don't forget to select **`dotall`** option.

**Notepad++**: Replace with: `\1wx_str\2`. Don't forget to select **`. matches newline`** option.

## Batch Mode

Notepad++ allows to find/replace in batch mode.

1. Open "**Find in Files**" dialog pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.
2. Copy-paste above regex to "**Find what**" box.
3. Copy-paste above replacement (`\1wx_str\2`) to "**Replace with**" box.
4. Specify **Directory** to find/replace in it.
5. Select **Regular Expression** in Search mode group box.
6. Check the `. matches newline` box.
7. Click to "**Find All**" button to view matches.
8. Click to "**Replace in Files**" button when you are sure to replace everything.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to match some condition that the two branch are nearly the same code statement, except on use "wx_str" and the other use "c_str"

Comment: @ollydbg23: I updated my answer to achieve this, assuming `wx_str` only occurs in first branch.

Comment: @ollydbg23: Please give me feedback, so I can help you improving the answer.

Comment: Hi, mmdemirbas, many thanks, I'm going to test it under notepad++, which I follow this tutorial:http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions

Comment: Ok, but this is not necessary. Only open Replace dialog (**Ctrl+H**), select **Regular Expression** as search mode and check the box with label **`. matches newline`**. Then fill in the **Find what** and **Replace with** boxes and click **Replace** button.

Comment: Thank, the replace works fine under Notepad++, but here are still two issues: 1, it looks like under Notepad++, after replace, there are still two new empty line after the first block(I use you example in http://regexr.com/?31oei), the second issue is that I would like to replace in many source files, would it possible to do this in a batch mode? Thanks again.

Comment: Extra newline eliminated adding `[\n\r]` to end of the regex. Batch mode explained in the updated answer.

Comment: Hi, I still have one issue, it looks like the first line of my example still can't be stripped, see my modified example in the link http://regexr.com?31olj , thanks.

Comment: Ok, this is my final example, I think it did strip the preprocessor line, see: http://regexr.com?31olm

Comment: Oh, sorry, I still found there is an issue, see the link: http://regexr.com?31ols, you can see the line "c" after the match, but after the replacement, the "c" is moving to right a bit.

Comment: How about [this](http://regexr.com?31omq): `\s+#if wxCHECK_VERSION\(2\, 9\, 0\)\s*(.*?)wx_str([^\r\n]*?)\s*#else\s*(\1)c_str(\2)\s*#endif`

Comment: Hi, this is what I finally used grammar(in notepad++), I keep the first branch unchanged, then removed all the line start with #, and the second branch. `\r\n[\t ]*#if wxCHECK_VERSION(2\, 9\, 0)\r\n([\t ]*.*?)wx_str(.*)\r\n[\t ]*#else\r\n(\1)c_str(\2)\r\n[\t ]*#endif` and the replace rule is `(\r\n)\1wx_str\2`

Answer (score 1):

Many simple regex tools do not support matching over multiple lines.  You could create a simple `awk` or `sed` script, or use Perl to smash the whole file into one long string;

```
perl -0777pe 's/^#if wxCHECK_VERSION\(2, 9, 0\)\n(.*?\n)(?:#else\n.*?\n)?#endif\n/\1/gsm' input.c >fixed.c
```

This does not attempt to account for variations in whitespace, and will not handle nested preprocessor directives.  If your matches are always a single line, it could be simplified.