# Regexp for C preprocessor command

Tags: c, regex

I am trying to write one regexp to match C preprocessor commands in C program. I wonder if you can give me some suggestions?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: How about this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826016/how-to-use-regex-to-strip-the-preprocessor-directive

Comment: regexp in which language/utility ?

Comment: One does not simply parse C using regexes. Nor can you parse HTML using `awk`. This didn't change recently.

Answer (score 1):

That would be

```
 grep '^[[:blank:]]*#'
```

Note that this will only grep the first line of a multi line preprocessor directive (continued with backslash newline).

Comment: Overall wisdom notwithstanding, I approve this answer and I wrote a preprocessor. The entire requirements for a directive are that it goes from a `#` or `%:` token following a newline, to just before the next newline. Whether the inside of the directive is well-formed is another matter. The other shortcoming of this approach is that it doesn't allow a comment before the `#`, but seriously who cares.

Comment: @Jens Thank you Jens. I will have a try later.

Answer (score 0):

May be this:
  (not too exact though)

```
\s*#\s*(define|error|import|undef|elif|if|include|using|else|ifdef|line|endif|ifndef|pragma)\s*\S*
```

You can use `cpp` and pass the option `-dM` to list out all defined macros.

`cpp -dM test.c`

Comment: can have space after #

Comment: That's not working. Some directives don't need anything to follow, and there's even the empty directive just consisting of '#'. Then, #import and #using are not C directives.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thank you for your reply. I will have a try.

Answer (score 0):

This regex illustrates how the backslash `\` newline can be integrated using recursive regex:

```
#(?<line>[^#].*?(\n|(\\[^\n]*\n(?&line))))
```

Hope this helps.